# Servers node not listed in services window in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, netbeans-7, glassfish-4

Trying to access my glassfish 4 server in Netbeans 7.4 and there are no "Server" or "Server Manager" under tools and there are no "Server" node in the Services window.  I added all the necessary plug-ins and I did access localhost:4848 and had the admin up and running on a prior package.  The package that I am running now is the oracle tutorial 7 packages for the web.

Anyone know why I can access my Glassfish Server or just administer which (web)servers in my NetBeans 7.4 IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the documentation here:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/framework-adding-support.html

I thought that I had the server set up right because I was able to access the admin console via a browser at port 4848, but alas, I didnt have it set up correctly.  I didnt follow the directions because once I saw where the plug-ins were I was able to determine what I needed as far as EJB's, and all the other web components.  As soon as I installed the right plugins (I think I chose 6 of them because of the modules I wanted) I saw that I now had a "Server" in the "Services" window, I changed the directory to my /Users/myName/glassfish4 directory instead of the recommended Glash_Fish, which might of been pointing to ver. 3 i think.

Anyhow, good Luck